# How to get records with null columns using Projection interface and native query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get a few properties of the records in a table of the database (and I need to make sub queries, hence I am using a native query) and for this I decided to use a Projection interface. No nested projections or anything of the sort.

I've tried to use SpEL annotations in the interface to expect null values, same result. I also tried to use a DTO instead but couldn't get it to work (always got the "no converter found" error) and I have no idea if it would even solve my problem.

Repository

```java
@Query(value =
        "SELECT " +
            "item.id AS id, " +
            "item.name AS name, " +
            "item.description AS description, " +
            "(CASE WHEN item.id NOT IN (SELECT bi.item_id " +
            "FROM t_booking_item bi " +
            "JOIN t_booking b on bi.booking_id = b.id " +
            "WHERE " +
            "(b.start_date >= :startDate AND b.start_date <= :endDate) " +
            "OR (b.end_date >= :startDate AND b.end_date <= :endDate) " +
            "OR (b.start_date < :startDate AND b.end_date > :endDate)" +
            ") THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS isAvailable, " +
            "item.barcode AS barcode, " +
            "item.serial_number AS serialnumber " +
            "FROM t_item item " +
            "WHERE item.category_id = :categoryId ", 

countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) " +
            "FROM t_item item " +
            "WHERE item.category_id = :categoryId ",

nativeQuery = true)
    Page<ItemAvailabilityView> findAllProjectedBy(@Param("categoryId") long categoryId, @Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate, @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate, Pageable pageable);
```

Projection interface

```java
public interface ItemAvailabilityView {

    Long getId();
    String getName();
    String getDescription();
    boolean getIsAvailable();
    String getBarcode();
    String getSerialnumber();
}
```

If the records on the database have all columns non null, it returns as expected. 
But, if one of those columns (that I'm expecting in the Projection) is null, that record is not returned. There's no errors, it just doesn't return the record. 
If I have a collection of records and all of them but one have filled columns, I'm able to get all the records except for the one with a null column.
In this specific case, it's the barcode column that is null, all other columns have correct values.

If I execute the query on the database, it works as expected. The problem appears to be with the projection.

Am I missing something, maybe some annotations to deal with null values? Or is it that projections don't really work with null values on columns?

Comment: You may try it without pagination and check the same behavior that exists. Beyond that, I wonder how your native query works with pagination without specifying an explicit count query?

Comment: Tried without pagination, same results. Tried it with one of the columns null and it didn't return. Same scenario but with all columns filled, and it returned as expected.

oh, didn't know it required a count query. I had it working because I didn't have enough items to require pagination on this specific case. Updated it with count query. Thanks!